# Merging two repositories by keeping only second repository files

Tags: git

I am working with two repositories a1 and a2. both are large in size. Team M is working with a1 repository. How to remove everything from a1 and push a2 repository's files into a1 so that M can still use a1 repository link and get all a2 repository files?

Tried cloning both repositories in local workspace, copy everything from a2 to a1 and push.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

First add a2 as remote in a1; assuming you are in a a1 checkout:

```
git remote add a2 https://the/path/to/a2.git
```

then fetch a2 to pull all commits:

```
git fetch a2
```

Then merge a2 in a1 (assuming you are on branch master of a1 and you want to merge stuff from master of a2):

```
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories a2/master
```

If both projects have no conflicting files this should be enough, I you have conflicts, you may fix them before finishing the merge.

Note that if you have many branches in a2 you ant to keep, you need to push them on a1 if you want them to be on a1 as well.

Also worth to notice that this just put all files together, it will not fix any build system or other project related stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. clone b repo
2. set remote: `git remote add <a good name> <git url of repo a>`, like `git remote repoA https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git`
3. git push , like: `git push repoA`